2D line tracing in a 3D environment
I am trying to build a grapple hook for my 2.5D platformer game.
First I started with creating a line trace between the character to the mouse cursor but I want to restrict the end point to always be 1090 at the Y coordinate (2D).
This is my current implementation:

